# Opening excels from different folders with python

Tags: python, excel, directory

Hi have a folder and inside that folder I have got nfolders(400)

In each of those folders I have several documents and one of them is an excel with a key name

Is there any possibility of oppening those excel as df1, df2,dfn?

Does anyone know how to Do a foor loop that opens each of those 400 folders?

Thanks!!

Comment: Google os.walk.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your excel files have extension '.xlsx'.
I use os.walk(path) from os package. os.walk traverses all the subfolders.
Put the path to the parent folder in path variable.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
path_to_parentfolder = 'Parent_Folder/'
files = []
for r, d, f in os.walk(path_to_parentfolder):
    for file in f:
        if '.xlsx' in file:          #Enter the extension for your file type 
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file).replace('/','\\'))
df_list = [pd.read_excel(open(file)) for file in files] #All your data is stored in the list
```

Read about os.walk in its [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)